# Stress test tool similar to Apache AB, concurrent requests from multiple IP

Tags: testing, stress-testing

I'm testing a web application using Apache AB; I love it but my web hosting service does not: if I increase the concurrency level over 30/40 I start getting 503 errors. The reason (according to the web hosting support) is that all the requests come from the same IP; do you know any other similar tool which can also simulate concurrent requests coming from different IPs?

Do you think the rule adopted by the hosting service is correct? For Optical Fiber internet connections, having many people who share the same IP is not so uncommon.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but you can try to use [Apache JMeter](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/197560-jmeter-video-tutorial-writing-your-first-jmeter-s). Just [run it remotely](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) from different IP

Comment: Hello, I was actually looking for something that simulate automatically different IP addresses (I guess an AB-like tool combined with a multiproxy service) but I don't know if it exists.

Comment: Yes, you can simulate different IP addresses. In HTTP Request sampler use property: Source IP Address. You can set IP here. To specify different IP you should add [CSV Data Set Config](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) and enumerate list of IP in CSV file.